# SQL ORACLE (DATE)

Tags: oracle, date

I want to insert a date from jsp that i have been make...

the date is format is 01-12-2016(DD-MM-YYYY) but it always said invalid month

My database date format is 05-DEC-16 (DD-MONTH-YYYY)

this is my function

```
insert into institution_exam(ACADEMIC_INSTITUITION_ID,place,start_date,end_date) values (i_e_id,V_place,(i_e_id,V_place,TO_DATE(V_date_start,'DD-MONTH-yyyy'),TO_DATE(V_date_end,'DD-MONTH-yyyy'));-----select max
```

there error
ORA-01843: not a valid month

any idea's??

Comment: Can you post the specific database structure

Comment: my datatype for startdate and enddate is date

Comment: I found this link that includes suggested data formats -- http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the title more informative. You've done nothing but repeat the tag information and add SQL, which is already clear because you tagged Oracle (and you could have included a SQL tag as well). Your title should have enough meaning to be useful to future users of this site who see it in a search result, not just a repetition of the tags. (While you're making that edit, you can fix your CAPS LOCK so you're not SHOUTING at us as well.) Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on one thing - does the date string contain "01-12-2016" or "01-12-2016(DD-MM-YYYY)"?

Comment: i insert using my interface with 01-12-2016 it fail,it said invalid month but when i insert with 01-DEC-2016 it successfully insert it because i see from my database sysdate it come out with this format 01-DEC-2016 so what should i do for insert using other format......

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_date()` with the appropriate format, DD-MM-YYYY:

```
insert into institution_exam(ACADEMIC_INSTITUITION_ID, place, start_date, end_date)
    values (i_e_id, V_place,
            TO_DATE(V_date_start, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
            TO_DATE(V_date_end, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
           );
```

Comment: 01-12-2016(DD-MM-YYYY) this is date that i passed from my interface for inserting

Comment: This is strange.  What is the data type of the two date variables?

Comment: when i pass data like this 01-DEC-2016 it ok the inserting completed but when i insert 01-12-2016 it fail

Answer (score 0):

This may help. Notice the difference between `MONTH` and `MON` in the date format model. It seems like your data uses the short name but in your query you are using `MONTH` instead of `MON`.

As an aside, notice how there is an extra space after `DECEMBER` in the long format... that's a "feature" in Oracle, where all month names (and same with week names), when spelled out in full, are all the same length - and padded with spaces to make them so. But that is probably irrelevant to your situation.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MONTH-YYYY') as long_month_name, 
       to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')   as short_month_name
from   dual;

LONG_MONTH_NAME    SHORT_MONTH_NAME
-----------------  ----------------
20-DECEMBER -2016  20-DEC-2016
```